# OLAP level-based measure drilldown issue

Tags: olap, measure, mondrian, multi-level

everyone!

Following the "Pentaho Analizer Cookbook" PDF, I tried to stablish a level-based measure.

My cube has a single dimension hierarchy: Clients that have Projects that have Buildings that have Phases that have Costlines level 0 that have Costlines level 1.

So, there let be samples for both fact and dimensions:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TMP_DEBUG_OLAP_13_FACTS;
CREATE  TABLE TMP_DEBUG_OLAP_13_FACTS AS
          SELECT 1 AS client_id,1 as project_id,1 as building_id,'1_1_1_1' as phase_id,'1_1_1_1_1' as costs_line_level_0_id,'1_1_1_1_1_1'  as costs_line_level_1_id,10 as amount
UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS client_id,1 as project_id,1 as building_id,'1_1_1_1' as phase_id,'1_1_1_1_2' as costs_line_level_0_id,'1_1_1_1_2_1'  as costs_line_level_1_id,20 as amount
UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS client_id,1 as project_id,1 as building_id,'1_1_1_2' as phase_id,'1_1_1_2_1' as costs_line_level_0_id,'1_1_1_2_1_1'  as costs_line_level_1_id,30 as amount
UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS client_id,1 as project_id,2 as building_id,'1_1_2_1' AS phase_id,'1_1_2_1_1' as costs_line_level_0_id,'1_1_2_1_1_1'  as costs_line_level_1_id,40 as amount
UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS client_id,2 as project_id,3 as building_id,'1_2_3_1' AS phase_id,'1_2_3_1_1' as costs_line_level_0_id,'1_2_3_1_1_1'  as costs_line_level_1_id,50 as amount
UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS client_id,2 as project_id,4 as building_id,'1_2_4_1' AS phase_id,'1_2_4_1_1' as costs_line_level_0_id,'1_2_4_1_1_1'  as costs_line_level_1_id,60 as amount
UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS client_id,3 as project_id,5 as building_id,'2_3_5_1' AS phase_id,'2_3_5_1_1' as costs_line_level_0_id,'2_3_5_1_1_-1' as costs_line_level_1_id,70 as amount
;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TMP_DEBUG_OLAP_13_DIMENSIONS;
CREATE TABLE TMP_DEBUG_OLAP_13_DIMENSIONS AS
          SELECT 1 AS client_id,'Client 1 name' AS client_name,1 as project_id,'Project 1' as project_name,1 as building_id,'Building 1' as building_name,'1_1_1_1' as phase_id,'Phase 1' as phase_name,'1_1_1_1_1' as costs_line_level_0_id,'1 blah' AS costs_line_level_0_name,'1_1_1_1_1_1'  AS costs_line_level_1_id,'1.1 blah' as costs_line_level_1_name                          
UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS client_id,'Client 1 name' AS client_name,1 as project_id,'Project 1' as project_name,1 as building_id,'Building 1' as building_name,'1_1_1_1' as phase_id,'Phase 1' as phase_name,'1_1_1_1_2' as costs_line_level_0_id,'2 blah' AS costs_line_level_0_name,'1_1_1_1_2_1'  AS costs_line_level_1_id,'2.1 blah' as costs_line_level_1_name
UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS client_id,'Client 1 name' AS client_name,1 as project_id,'Project 1' as project_name,1 as building_id,'Building 1' as building_name,'1_1_1_2' as phase_id,'Phase 2' as phase_name,'1_1_1_2_1' as costs_line_level_0_id,'1 blah' AS costs_line_level_0_name,'1_1_1_2_1_1'  AS costs_line_level_1_id,'1.1 blah' as costs_line_level_1_name
UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS client_id,'Client 1 name' AS client_name,1 as project_id,'Project 1' as project_name,2 as building_id,'Building 2' as building_name,'1_1_2_1' as phase_id,'Phase 1' as phase_name,'1_1_2_1_1' as costs_line_level_0_id,'1 blah' AS costs_line_level_0_name,'1_1_2_1_1_1'  AS costs_line_level_1_id,'1.1 blah' as costs_line_level_1_name
UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS client_id,'Client 1 name' AS client_name,2 as project_id,'Project 2' as project_name,3 as building_id,'Building 3' as building_name,'1_2_3_1' as phase_id,'Phase 1' as phase_name,'1_2_3_1_1' as costs_line_level_0_id,'1 blah' AS costs_line_level_0_name,'1_2_3_1_1_1'  AS costs_line_level_1_id,'1.1 blah' as costs_line_level_1_name
UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS client_id,'Client 1 name' AS client_name,2 as project_id,'Project 2' as project_name,4 as building_id,'Building 4' as building_name,'1_2_4_1' as phase_id,'Phase 1' as phase_name,'1_2_4_1_1' as costs_line_level_0_id,'1 blah' AS costs_line_level_0_name,'1_2_4_1_1_1'  AS costs_line_level_1_id,'1.1 blah' as costs_line_level_1_name
UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS client_id,'Client 2 name' AS client_name,3 as project_id,'Project 3' as project_name,5 as building_id,'Building 5' as building_name,'2_3_5_1' as phase_id,'Phase 1' as phase_name,'2_3_5_1_1' as costs_line_level_0_id,'1 blah' AS costs_line_level_0_name,'2_3_5_1_1_-1' AS costs_line_level_1_id,'1.1 blah' as costs_line_level_1_name
--non-crosing dimentions                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS client_id,'Client 2 name' AS client_name,3 as project_id,'Project 3' as project_name,5 as building_id,'Building 5' as building_name,'2_3_5_1' as phase_id,'Phase 1' as phase_name,'2_3_5_1_2' as costs_line_level_0_id,'2 blah' AS costs_line_level_0_name,'2_3_5_1_2_1'  AS costs_line_level_1_id,'2.1 blah' as costs_line_level_1_name
UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS client_id,'Client 2 name' AS client_name,3 as project_id,'Project 3' as project_name,5 as building_id,'Building 5' as building_name,'2_3_5_1' as phase_id,'Phase 1' as phase_name,'2_3_5_1_3' as costs_line_level_0_id,'3 blah' AS costs_line_level_0_name,'2_3_5_1_3_1'  AS costs_line_level_1_id,'3.1 blah' as costs_line_level_1_name
UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS client_id,'Client 2 name' AS client_name,3 as project_id,'Project 3' as project_name,5 as building_id,'Building 5' as building_name,'2_3_5_1' as phase_id,'Phase 1' as phase_name,'2_3_5_1_4' as costs_line_level_0_id,'4 blah' AS costs_line_level_0_name,NULL           AS costs_line_level_1_id,'4.1 blah' as costs_line_level_1_name
;
```

And my calculated measure is such as

```
([Measures].[My measure] , Ancestor([Dimensions].CurrentMember , [Dimensions].[Building]) )
```

The whole cube's xml (Mondrian) is as follows:

```
<Schema name="level_based_measure_unit_test">
  <Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" name="Dimensions">
    <Hierarchy name="Dimensions hierarchy" visible="true" hasAll="true" primaryKey="costs_line_level_1_id">
      <Table name="tmp_debug_olap_13_dimensions" schema="public" alias="">
      </Table>
      <Level name="Clients" visible="true" column="client_id" nameColumn="client_name" uniqueMembers="false">
      </Level>
      <Level name="Project" visible="true" column="project_id" nameColumn="project_name" uniqueMembers="false">
      </Level>
      <Level name="Building" visible="true" column="building_id" nameColumn="building_name" uniqueMembers="false">
      </Level>
      <Level name="Phase" visible="true" column="phase_id" nameColumn="phase_name" uniqueMembers="false">
      </Level>
      <Level name="Cost lines level 0" visible="true" column="costs_line_level_0_id" nameColumn="costs_line_level_0_name" uniqueMembers="false">
      </Level>
      <Level name="Cost lines level 1" visible="true" column="costs_line_level_1_id" nameColumn="costs_line_level_1_name" uniqueMembers="false">
      </Level>
    </Hierarchy>
  </Dimension>
  <Cube name="My cube" visible="true" cache="true" enabled="true">
    <Table name="tmp_debug_olap_13_facts" schema="public" alias="">
    </Table>
    <DimensionUsage source="Dimensions" name="Dimensions" visible="true" foreignKey="costs_line_level_1_id">
    </DimensionUsage>
    <Measure name="My measure" column="amount" aggregator="sum" visible="true">
    </Measure>
    <CalculatedMember name="My leveled measure" formatString="" formula="([Measures].[My measure] , Ancestor([Dimensions].CurrentMember , [Dimensions].[Building]) )" dimension="Measures" visible="true">
    </CalculatedMember>
  </Cube>
</Schema>
```

I have 1 problem with that formula:

It displays a value at building level, but drillind-down, it keeps its value.

Picture of what I mean:

[image: Problem: It doesnt drill-down good]

Does anyone know how should I change my calculated member, so it displays the measure [My measure] but only on Building level and below?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Pentaho Analizer Cookbook specifies, that Formula is for pinning a `Measure` to a certain level.

It is: if you drill-down, you'll get the value as the drill-up.

If what you need (if I understood correctly) is to just display nothing for upper-levels, then user the next Formula:

`IIF([Dimensions].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal < 3 , NULL , [Measures].[My measure] )`